# Integrate $e^{\sqrt{(2x+1)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $e^{\sqrt{(2x+1)}}$

what I did :
let $u=2x+1$
,$du=2dx$

I plugged in those value and did the integration, is this wrong? as my answer is said to be wrong and it was solved by integration by parts instead of u-sub

Comment: You are correct that it is straightforward to integrate $e^{\sqrt{u}}$ by parts.

Answer (score 1):

That's not wrong, per se. (in the sense that the substitution is a valid one) but when you got $\int 2 e^{\sqrt{u}} du$, how did you "do the integration"?

A better approach might be to see that the square root is a problem, and let 
$$
u^2 = 2x + 1 \\
2u du = 2dx
$$
so that you get 
$$
\int e^u u ~ du
$$
which is then amenable to integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may perform the change of variable $u=\sqrt{2x+1}$, $dx=u du$, giving
$$
\int e^{\sqrt{(2x+1)}}dx=\int ue^{u}du
$$ then integrate by parts.

Comment: @user332428 If you do so, then you have to know the antiderivative $\int e^\sqrt{u}du$. How do you know the latter?

Comment: A change of variable may bring you to a familiar path :)